# VSDBCMD returns "An unexpected failure occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, build-process

I have been succesfully using the command line database deployment tool VSDBCMD on my dev and test environments but the tool fails in our integration environmrnt. I am using the VS 2010 version of the tool. The servers have all of the prerequisites including:

- .net 4.0
- sql server compact edition 3.5 sp1 (as well as the full edition of 2008)
- sql server 2008 server management objects
- sql server 2008 native client
- sql server system clr types
- msxml 6
- all of the dependent DLLs included in:

  - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\desktop*.dll
  - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5*.dll
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy***.*

The only reference to this error that I have been able to find has to do with a bug in the VS 2008 edition when the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0 key is missing. In my case the 10.0 version of the key exists.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Barclay Hill for suggesting that I install SP2 of SQLCE. This is a new dependency of 2010.